# who actually calls __iter__ method

Tags: python

I am learning python and just started reading about iterators and iterables , I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols) post and [this](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html) post both which try to explain this concept. However when reading this example. I have posted it below

```
class zrange:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        return zrange_iter(self.n)

class zrange_iter:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.i = 0
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        # Iterators are iterables too.
        # Adding this functions to make them so.
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.i < self.n:
            i = self.i
            self.i += 1
            return i
        else:
            raise StopIteration()
```

Now the above example is being used as such

```
>>> z = zrange(5)
>>> list(z)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

My question is when or who calls the **iter** method ?

and my next question was what was the point of adding   `def __iter__(self)`
in class `zrange_iter` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__iter__` is called by the `iter` builtin, and is also used to support iteration in the `for ... in ...` loop.